# Что означает эта строчка? C#

Tags: c#

```
public class Program 
{ 
   public static void Main()
   {    
       Program p = new Program(); // вот эта строчка
   }
}
```

Comment: Вызов конструктора и создание объекта класса Program?

Comment: @KoVadim, не `?`, а `!`.

Answer (score 0):

Это создание объекта класса Program посмотри [ссылку](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes)

Answer (score 0):

`Program p = new Program`

`Program` - обозначает класс, в котором Вы создаете объект `p`(примерно тоже самое как `int`, `string` (это не точное сравнение , но думаю Вы поймете)

`p`- именование объекта в классе `Progaram`.

Comment: У Вас некорректная формулировка в фразе "`p` - именование объекта в классе `Program`". Это ссылка на экземпляр класса `Program`

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще дополнить: Оператор new выделяет память для объекта Person. И затем вызывается конструктор по умолчанию, который не принимает никаких параметров.В итоге после выполнения данного выражения в памяти будет выделен участок, где будут храниться все данные объекта Program.Подробнее написано тут.  https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.1.php ,                    https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes , https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/classes-and-objects.